# Getting ACF relationship field information

Tags: custom-post-types, php, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use ACF Relationships to associate members to different committees. On the front end, I want to have the committee name and the board members that are associated with them. I have attempted to follow the [ACF Relationship](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) guide, several stack answers, and other stuff, but am pretty new to WP so I have been unsuccessful.

**Here are screenshots of my Wordpress setup**
[image]
[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'committees');
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if (have_posts()): 
        while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <li style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>
        <h5 style='margin: 0;'><?php echo the_field("committee_name"); ?></h5>
        <ul>
            <li>associated committee members repeated here</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

**Edits**

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'committees');
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if (have_posts()): 
    while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();
    $members = get_field('committee_members', $member->ID);
?>
<li style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>
    <h5 style='margin: 0;'><?php echo the_field("committee_name"); ?></h5>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($members as $member)
            echo "<li>";
            echo $member->post_title;
            echo "</li>";
        ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php 
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mentioned your issue, but didn't mention an error, or a specific question. What's not working?

Comment: Whenever I try to use something like foreach( $posts as $post): to iterate over the data, the php always breaks the page. All I really want is to be able to show the association under the committee.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship fields can either return an Objects or a Post IDs. That's up to you (you can choose it when creating the field). Either way that object or ID would be returned inside an array, because the field gives you the option to select multiple values.

So in your loop:

```
$members = get_field('committee_members'); // assuming that's the field slug

//if it's returning the object

foreach($members as $member){

  echo $member->post_title; //member name

}
```

That would assign all Committee Members to $members. Then you just need to loop through all $members and print their name, or anything else you need that's related to that post. If the Committee Member also has ACF custom fields you can access it by using:

```
get_field("YOU_FIELD_NAME", $member->ID);
```

Comment: I updated the code by your reference, and it works but is only outputting the last member from the first committee onto all committees. I am adding a screenshot to a edit above.

Comment: Remove $member->ID from get_field

Comment: I just updated it, and they last of that specific committee was still just showing up. I put in a arrow to see if it was iterating through them, and a arrow with the correct amount of people is being output but not the member name itself. Screenshot added in edits for reference.